# How can I automate analyzing matrices stored in a mat file?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, file-io, mat-file

I've got a multidimensional .mat file with a bunch of m x n arrays where each one is called something different, for example `f1`, `f2`, etc. I want to open the .mat file up and analyze each file automatically. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

If you know for certain that *all* the variables in the .mat file are M-by-N arrays to be processed, then this should work:

```
data = load('your_file.mat');   %# Load .mat file data into a structure
for name = fieldnames(data).'  %'# Loop over the field names of the structure
  mat = data.(name{1});         %# Get one structure field (i.e. matrix)
  %# Process matrix here
end
```

The above uses the functions [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) and [`fieldnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html), and accesses structure fields using [dynamic field names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't know about MATLAB's dynamic field references. +1

Comment: +1 also as a note, one can get the variable names inside a MAT-file using `who -file file.mat`